# Alterar tabela users Auth Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, auth

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema usando Laravel 5.1 e não quero usar tabelas em inglês. Na verdade estou tentando manter o padrão seguido aqui na empresa.

Gostaria de saber se consigo usar o `Auth` ou `OAuth` e mudar a tabela de *users* para *usuarios*, e consequentemente seus campos, por exemplo: *senha* ao invés de *password*. Além de adicionar mais informações pessoais e níveis de acesso.

Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Comment: Consegue sim, no arquivo de configuração `config/auth.php`

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro faça alteração do nome da tabela em [config/auth.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php):

```
'table' => 'users',
```

Adicione a variável `$username` ao arquivo [app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php)

```
protected $username = 'username';
```

Para alterar as colunas `name`, `password`, etc., será necessário criar um novo driver para auth. Um exemplo comum é um driver para LDAP onde os campos do LDAP são diferentes dos utilizados pelo framework.

Comment: Bruno, alterar a config da forma que você mostrou não resolve o problema, pois ele depende do driver de auth utilizado (eloquent ou database).

Comment: @gmsantos você está certo, obrigado pela observação!

Comment: Você consegui realizar o que queria? Se sim, marque a resposta correta.

Answer (score 2):

Sim.

No arquivo **app/auth.php** você tem que mudar essas duas linhas:

```
'model' => 'App\User',
'table' => 'users',
```

Mude para o nome da tabela que você criou.

Lembrando que o nome da tabela no banco deve ser no **Plural** e no Laravel o Model deve estar no **Singular**.